# Placing a specific record at end of a query

Tags: php, sql, loops

In the query I have order by name (alphabetically), stick the query in $res, and then loop over the results.

```
while($rs = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
    echo $rs['name'];
}
```

Now in that while loop there is a "webmaster" name. I need to take "Webmaster" and place it at the end of the loop (so it echoes out last) or place "Webmaster / Affiliate ProgramsWebshops" in $res (at the end of the query before hitting the while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easiest way would be to edit your query and change the ordering from:

```
ORDER BY
  name
```

to

```
ORDER BY
  IF(name LIKE 'webmaster',1,0),
  name
```

note: this `IF` is mysql-syntax - you havn't posted wich database you're using. on postgres it would be something like (not 100% sure):

```
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN name ILIKE 'webmaster' THEN 1 ELSE 0 ,
  name
```

**EDIT** to explain this: by changing the order this way, it's like putting an additional column to the ordering that contains `1` if the name is "webmaster" or `0` in every other case. by ordering by this "column" first, the "webmaster" is always at the end (or: all "webmaster"s - if there are more than one)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
$webmasterArray = array();
while($rs = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    if($rs['name'] == "webmaster")
        $webmasterArray = $rs;
    else
        echo $rs['name'];
}
if($webmasterArray)
    echo $webmasterArray['name'];
```

Comment: ... which will give you shitloads of warnings since you do not check that the element exists before `echo`ing it, and you do not even create the `Array` to start with!